# Push promise data into object array

Tags: angular, typescript

How I can push the data of the promise inside `this.players`?In this code `this.players` is undefined  when I try to push

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDataServiceService } from './my-data-service.service';
import { Player } from './player';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  players:Player[];

  constructor ( private service:MyDataServiceService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      var json_data = data.json().resultSets[0]['rowSet'];
      for (let player of json_data) {
        this.players.push(new Player(player[0],player[1],player[3],player[4]));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: initialize the array `players:Player[] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

If Player is a Model you can do something like this.

```
players: Array<Player> = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator

```
this.players = [ ...this.players, ...player];
```